# Send MFA token with access key for S3 bucket, file upload using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to add MFA (Multi Factor Authentication) in my application, where i am going to store object in aws S3 bucket. I went through AWS documentation but could not find anything where we can pass MFA tokedn while sending any request to AWS programmatically in C#.

Here is my working code snippet without MFA,

```
var awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
_client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
{

BucketName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["S3BucketName"],
Key = fileName,
FilePath = localFilePath,
ContentType = "image/" + Path.GetExtension(fileName),
CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
};
var req = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(putRequest);
```

I am expecting to add MFA authentication token to this above code.

Answer (score 0):

The TOTP from an MFA token isn't passed directly with the request.

Instead, you first make a call to Security Token Service (STS) where you essentially "exchange" your current credentials and MFA info for a set of temporary credentials that are used to authenticate subsequent requests.

> The user calls one of the AWS STS API operations that support the MFA parameters, `AssumeRole` or `GetSessionToken`, depending on the scenario for MFA protection, as explained later. As part of the call, the user includes the device identifier for the device that's associated with the user. The user also includes the time-based one-time password (TOTP) that the device generates. In either case, the user gets back temporary security credentials that the user can then use to make additional requests to AWS.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_configure-api-require.html

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I have tried with GetSessionToken() method, from this i am getting sessionToken credentials which iam passing as paremeter while creating AmazonS3Client object, this object am using to upload image to S3 bucket. Please refer my below code here, Please advice if this code is sufficient enough to pass MFA programmatically.

Comment: `var client = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(new BasicAWSCredentials("AK", "SK"),Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            var sessionTokenResult = client.GetSessionToken();
            Credentials sessionCredentials = sessionTokenResult.Credentials;
            AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(sessionCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
            {
                //Parameters
            };
                var response = s3Client.PutObject(putRequest)`

Comment: You need to send the device serial number and current TOTP with the `GetSessionToken()` request.  Then, when you use the resulting temporary credentials, the the fact that the *session* was established with MFA is known to the downstream services.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_sample-code.html

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for reply, The shared link contains the console application code, where User has to enter the MFA code manually. This will not solve problem for me. As i need to pass the MFA authentication token automatically through program C#. I am requesting you to suggest how to pass this MFA token through programmatically without any manual inputs. I have searched in AWS documents but i didnt got any proper documentation for sending MFA token automatically by using any virtual device token. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rakesh that isn't what I thought you were asking.  You asked how to *send* the token, which is done in the call to GetSessionToken and requires no manual step.  The manual step is reading the token from the device, which is usually done token → eyeballs → fingers → application.  *Automated itegration* with a virtual MFA is outside my expertise and seems like it would vary by device implementation, assuming it's possible at all.